# Is there a way to check if a TCP payload is of type MQTT, and if so decode its header values in Python?

Tags: mqtt

I'm using scapy to read a pcap file, but scpay only decodes up to the transport layer it seems. My goal is to retrieve MQTT header flags, but I need a way to check if the application layer is MQTT in the first place, and then a way to decode packet headers.

I've tried using PyShark but my pcap file is too large and it takes too long.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77732328/edit) to show your PyShark code as this will be the correct solution and we may be able to help you make it faster.

Comment: Surely the port number(1883) will be sufficient to filter MQTT packets?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a time-efficient but memory-costly solution - pcap files can be converted to json using a tshark command

```
tshark -r input.pcap -T json > output.json
```

which can then be converted to csv format. The reason I chose not to convert directly to csv using wireshark is that wireshark removes a lot of information when converting to csv, while json maintains the whole frame 'tree'. Json files do take up way more space though.